# How to rename a file in a different folder within the directory?

Tags: r

I have a file name called `0.pdf`, and I want to move this file to a different folder in the same directory called `issues`. But I also want to keep this `0.pdf` in the original place because this file is needed for other functions. I can do the below to move the file to the `issues` folder.

```
file.copy("0.pdf","issues")
```

However, I want to also rename the "0.pdf" in the new folder `issues` based on a variable value `x`, if `x=5`, I want the file name in the `issues` folder to be `5.pdf` for example. How can I do that? If I use `file.rename` then `file.copy`, it would get rid of the `0.pdf` in the original place. How can I move the file, then rename the file in the new folder?

```
x=5
file.rename(paste(x,".pdf"))
file.copy(paste(x,".pdf"), "issues")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.copy` takes either a directory path or the full file path as its `to` argument. So you can write:

```
file.copy('0.pdf', file.path('issues', paste0(x, '.pdf')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
x <- 5
filename <- "0.pdf"
file.copy(filename,paste0("issues/", sub('.*(?=\\.pdf)',x,filename, perl = TRUE)))
```

`sub` would replace the filename (without extension) to the value `x`.

```
sub('.*(?=\\.pdf)', x, filename, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "5.pdf"
```